# Persisting an array to use on another html page

Tags: javascript, html, function, persist

I need to be able to display from information in an array.

A selection is chosen by checkboxes, which is stored in the temporarySelection, then the temporarySelection info is transferred to other arrays (eg. added to restaurantSelection, then cleared for the next choices).

I need to then be able to display these arrays on a separate html page.

There's 4 different arrays to transfer to the second html page, placeSelection, hotelSelection, restaurantSelections, and sightSelections.

I've had a look around, tried a few different things, but nothing seems to be working.

Any ideas?

I've already attempted to use localstorage in a function (although I may not hav got it quite right).

Looked into cookies but I've been told not to do this as it is unnecessary as only Javascript will be using it.

```
function chooseSelection(resultIndex) {

    var locationName = document.getElementById('locationName-' + resultIndex);

    if(!temporarySelection.includes(locationName.innerHTML)) {
        console.log('pushing ' + locationName.innerHTML + ' into 
        temporarySelection')
        temporarySelection.push(locationName.innerHTML);
    } else {
        var index = temporarySelection.indexOf(locationName.innerHTML);
        console.log('Removing index number: ', index)
        temporarySelection.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

I hope that the second html page, the "results page" will show the arrays for placeSelection, hotelSelection, restaurantSelections, and sightSelections in 4 separate boxes.

Comment: "I've already attempted to use localstorage in a function (although I may not hav got it quite right)." — That is a sensible approach … but there's no [mcve] of your attempt so we have no way to tell why it didn't work.

Comment: Is the second page on the same domain?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you are setting local storage. Below are the two small functions to set and get values for your array in store.

```
function setStore(temporarySelection){
    localStorage.setItem("temporarySelection", JSON.stringify(temporarySelection));
}

function getStore(){
        const temporarySelection  = localStorage.getItem("temporarySelection"); 
      if(temporarySelection)
      {
        return JSON.parse(temporarySelection)
      }
      else{
        return [];
      }
    }
```

Here is your code with these functions in use

```
function chooseSelection(resultIndex) {

    var locationName = document.getElementById('locationName-' + resultIndex);

    if(!temporarySelection.includes(locationName.innerHTML)) {
        console.log('pushing ' + locationName.innerHTML + ' into 
        temporarySelection')
        temporarySelection.push(locationName.innerHTML);
    } else {
        var index = temporarySelection.indexOf(locationName.innerHTML);
        console.log('Removing index number: ', index)
        temporarySelection.splice(index, 1);
    }
    setStore(temporarySelection)
}
```

Now you can get your store values with getStore function in any page.